# format value that could be number and/or string in python 3

Tags: python, string-formatting, number-formatting

Is there a concise way of formatting a number, that on occasion can also be a string?

The number would normally be a float, but occasionally it's also denoted as the string "n/a".

I would like to format the float with a fixed number of decimals, but print the entire string in case it is not a number.

For instance:

```
var=3.145623
print("This is {0:.2f}".format(var))

>>>This is 3.14
```

,but

```
var = "n/a"
print("This is {0:.2f}".format(var))

>>> File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>>> ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'
```

I am not surprised by the ValueError, but wonder if there is a concise way around it, ideally without an explicit if-statement.

Comment: It seems like using an explicit `if-else` is the most straightforward way... This is the problem you get when you deal with mixed types, and why you should avoid it when possible.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I just though that I missed a switch in .format() or something - to me it seems that this would be a problem people likely run into quite frequently and hence there might be something built-in already...

Comment: May I ask, why is it even possible that you get either a `float` or the string `"n/a"`? It seems that is the real problem.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Well, that's the input data I am working with. Technically speaking, I convert the numbers from string to float first, of course, but I omitted this from the question as it seems not immediately relevant to the problem of formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python supports not-a-number as `float('nan')` and it may be more useful than the string "n/a" in your code. It works with formatting and produces more sane results than a string if you use it in computations.

NaN:

```
>>> n = float('nan')
>>> n
nan
>>> "{0:.2f}".format(n)
'nan'
>>> n == 3
False
>>> n * 2
nan
>>> n < 5
False
```

String:

```
>>> n = 'n/a'
>>> "{0:.2f}".format(n)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'
>>> n == 3
False
>>> n * 2
'n/an/a'
>>> n < 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
```

Comment: This is what I ended using in the end - converting the "n/a"-value to "nan".

Answer (score 7):

Indeed, the `f` format specifier only works on actual `float` values. You can't avoid having to special-case your `n/a` value.

You can format the float *separately*, and conditionally, then interpolate the result into the larger template:

```
var_formatted = format(var, '.2f') if var != 'n/a' else var
print("This is {0:4}".format(var_formatted))
```

If you are really averse to `if`, you can use exception handling too:

```
try:
    var_formatted = format(var, '.2f')
except ValueError:
    var_formatted = 'n/a'
print("This is {0:4}".format(var_formatted))
```

Another option would be for you to wrap the value in a class with a `__format__` method:

```
class OptionalFloat(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __format__(self, fmt):
        try:
            return self.value.__format__(fmt)
        except ValueError:
            return self.value

print("This is {0:.2f}".format(OptionalFloat(var)))
```

This moves the requirement to detect the type into another class method, keeping your output code a little cleaner and free of all those pesky conditionals or exception handlers:

```
>>> var = 3.145623
>>> print("This is {0:.2f}".format(OptionalFloat(var)))
This is 3.15
>>> var = 'n/a'
>>> print("This is {0:.2f}".format(OptionalFloat(var)))
This is n/a
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this

```
str = "{0:.2f}".format(var) if isinstance(var, float) else var
print(str)
```